# Best practice injecting service into another service

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, architecture

We suppose that I have Two Entity (***Subscription*** and ***Application***) and for each one his Repository layer named (***SubscriptionRepository*** and ***ApplicationRepository***) and two Service for each one (***ISubscriptionService*** and ***IApplicationService***)

In some case, suppose we end up with `a case where  ApplicationService need to inject SubscriptionService`  and `a case where SubscriptionService need to inject ApplicationService` (
the reverse) and and of course it Is a ***Circular Dependency***

My question is:

When I want to inject service into another how I should reflect to not fall into this type of problem. (it means how i can decide if i need to inject ApplicationService into SubscriptionService or the reverse)?

Answer (score 1):

You could invert the dependencies of both services to each other by making both depend on another abstraction instead. In your case, as both are domain services, ***domain events*** emitted by either your entities or the domain services could be a good fit.

But without knowing more details about your domain and what *Application* and *Subscription* are dedicated for it is hard to tell if you are not facing a design problem.

***If*** you think there is a design flaw I suggest to ask yourself these questions which often help me when I am not sure if I have drawn the correct boundaries in my domain model.

- Would it make more sense to *merge these two components* which are dependent on each other?
- Does my *component A* access some feature of *component B* which should rather be part of *component A*?
- Does my *component B* access some feature of *component A* which should rather be part of *component B*?
- Should functionality of A or B which are accessed by the other rather be in a third not yet discovered component? This could be another interface, domain events or something similar...